# SharePoint Designer 2013: Including Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, designer

I'm trying to include the following code into SharePoint Designer on a web page. How can I best do this?

When I copy-paste, no results show. The site below mentions using a content editor web part, but that option is disabled for the web page I'm using because of how heavily customized it was. So I have to insert this code through SP Designer.

https://www.dalesandro.net/display-file-last-updated-date-using-jquery-sharepoint/